# Bootstrap and wysihtml5 updating textarea

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, textarea, wysihtml5

I'm using :

- wysihtml5
- bootstrap-wysihtml5.js

I have a textarea called Booking_CancellationComments_CancellationPolicy and am making it a wysihtml5 textarea using this code:

```
$('#Booking_CancellationComments_CancellationPolicy').wysihtml5(options);
```

I'm trying to update it later using:

```
$('#Booking_CancellationComments_CancellationPolicy').val(data.Booking.CancellationComments.CancellationPolicy);
```

But the textarea isn't updating.  I've looked at lots of answers on Stack Overflow and not show how to update the textarea using the initialisation method I've used.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

`$('#Booking_CancellationComments_CancellationPolicy').data("wysihtml5").editor.setValue(data.Booking.CancellationComments.CancellationPolicy);`

Comment: What problem if $("#Description").data('wysihtml5').editor = 
undefined. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

//for editor = undefined. the constructor does not initialize the editor

```
var wysihtml5 =   $("#Booking_CancellationComments_CancellationPolicy").wysihtml5() ;
wysihtml5 = wysihtml5.data("wysihtml5");
wysihtml5.createEditor({}); "create the editor
```

....

```
wysihtml5.editor.setValue("some html");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with editor == 'undefined' and resolved it with this:

```
$('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents().find('body').html('<b>New text</a>');
```

I know, it's not best solution, but only this works for me. If you have better solution, please let me know.